# Fragment executes a method from the previous activity when edittext is focused

Tags: android, android-activity, view, focus, fragment

I have an activity A (navigation drawer) that launches some fragments

The activity A contains this:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    //create dialog to close the app
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't matter the fragment where I am, when I touch the back button *and* I have an `EditText` focused in the current layout, it *will* launch the dialog.

This means that if I want to close the app, I have to be in the main window, and touch back button and it asks me if I want to leave. 
But if I am in any fragment and touch the back button wile an `EditText` is focused, it also launches the dialog, overriding the behavior of the back button that I have set in that current fragment.

When I touch back button on a fragment this is what it excecutes if the `EditText` is not focused, which work perfectly:

```
view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
view.requestFocus();
view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
           //stuff
        }
    }
});
```

If an `EditText` is focused, it will execute the code for the back button in the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone?
I am sure that it is related to context, focus or something like that, but still can't figure out why